# WiX Custom Action assembly merging for general use vs ILMerge

Tags: .net, wix, ilmerge

When .NET custom action projects are built using the WiX toolset, it appears to merge in all potentially needed code from direct project references while discarding code paths that will not be needed.  Is this a correct interpretation of the behavior, and if so, what kind of shortcomings might there be (such as reflection issues)?

Can this system be somehow leveraged for more general usage outside of installer projects in place of ILMerge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `makesfxca.exe` (that's the tool your talking about, aren't you?) is not merging dll's in a pure technical sense. It rather takes its own native "stub"-dll named `SfxCA.dll` appends / packs other dependencies (e.g. WIX's own `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller` as well as the managed dll containing the IL-code for the custom action) creating a native dll capable of "self extraction". On installing an msi this archive is temporarly extracted.

Thus it "resolves" the project references by copying the dll's passed in to `makesfxca` being able to omit the inclusion of just referenced but not locally copied .Net framework dll's. I'm not sure whether it really will discard anything.

`ILMerge`on the other side handles managed dll files, doing a real merge, rather than packing and later on extracting files.

Comment: Well, in one installer project, I have 23 MB of references that had to be chainged in, which reduce down into a custom actions DLL of about 2.7MB.

Comment: As long as you just reference e.g. .Net 2.0 dll's like `System.Data` or `System.XML` and do not copy them to the output directory (assuming a standard DTF build process), you do not drag those librararies into the resulting `*.CA.dll`. E.g. setting the flag "Copy local" to true for `System.Data` results in a `*.CA.dll` being 800 KBytes bigger (this probably evaluates to the compressed size of the library, its original size being 2884 KBytes on my machine).

Comment: I'm not counting .NET framework references, though.  These are internally developed managed code assemblies from another solution.  Basically, I'm referencing class A, B, and C.  Not all of any of them are used, but A calls some methods in B which call some methods in C that get used during install.  Meanwhile, the full size of A, B, and C far exceeds the size of the outputted DLL that manages to work.

Comment: Edited my answer expanding on things mentioned in my above comment.

Comment: Cool, so you're saying all it's actually doing is compressing ALL references, whether they're used or not, and putting them in an unmanaged assembly?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty confident `makesfxca` does not have any logic to determine what to include in the resulting, compressed `*.CA.dll`. It just takes all the files mentioned on the command line as the 4th, 5th, ... argument.

Comment: I'm not directly using that executable since I'm just using the WiX custom action project template, but I'm guessing it's being used at compilation anyway.

Comment: Exactly. You may use e.g. sysinternal's `procmon` to see the call to the `makesfxca` executable on build or dig into the internals of VS project files; look for the import of the `$(WixCATargetsPath)` project and follow this trail. Good luck! :-)